# How do I refer to form object within report code

Tags: vba, database-design, ms-access-2016

I know I had a similar post but it was closed before it was solved. I have more information now that might help. All the code is on the report vba module. So I’m trying to call a form object with report code

Code:

```
    Do.Cmd.OpenForm “FormOne”, acNormal
    Forms!FormOne.Visible = False 

    If Forms!FormOne.Form!Authorization.Value = 1 Then 
       Me.Label1.Caption = “Report A Details” 
    ElseIf Forms!FormOne.Form!Authorization.Value = 2 Then
       Me.Label1.Caption = “Report B Details” 
    End If
    End Sub
```

The part where I open the form and make it invisible works. The If/Else statement doesn’t work but also doesn’t give any errors. I also tried replacing the second (!) with (.) but the same thing happened.

Because question was typed on iPad my quotes look like smart quotes.

Comment: Try with `Forms!FormOne!Authorization.Value `.

Comment: @Gustav I just tried this, but t didn’t work. Thank you!

Comment: A form is used to interact with the user. A report is essentially a read-only object. Opening an invisible form from within the report code and using the values of the form properties to set report properties seems backwards. Normally, you would display the form, wait for the user to click a button or something, then open the report and set the report properties from within the form code.

Comment: @NicholasHunter I actually loaded the code on the Report_Load event. I understand what you are saying I will try doing it this way. Do you know how to refer to a report’s object within a form? 

Pretty much, I have a report that has two sub-reports. Based on a certain value within the form I want the report title caption to change.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to set the title using the report OpenArgs property. Here is your form button click event.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim args As Variant

    If Me.Authorization.Value = 1 Then
       args = "Report A Details"
    ElseIf Me.Authorization.Value = 2 Then
       args = "Report B Details"
    End If

    DoCmd.OpenReport "Report1", acViewPreview, OpenArgs:=args
    
End Sub
```

and here is the report open event

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
        Me.Label1.Caption = Me.OpenArgs
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to me. I’ll try this now.

Comment: So the report still opens but the labels don’t change. Now I already have some text within the label I want to manipulate (Label1), could this be the problem? If I delete the text in the design view of the report the label disappears too.

Comment: Or does the report already need to be opened in order to make changes? In this case we called the acViewPreview after the If/Else statement.

Comment: My example assumes that the report is called Report1 and the control you're trying to change is a label called Label1. You need to make sure the label is wide enough to show the required text. It doesn't matter what the label caption is at design time because it will be replaced by the contents of the report's OpenArgs property at run time. The label caption will nor change unless you open the report by executing the Command_Click1 sub. You need to set that up to execute when the button on the form is clicked.